# Bootstrap dropdown menu is not showing on fullscreen CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have added bootstrap 3.3.7 to my project. And added the top fixed navbar in HTML. everything working fine but the Dropdown is not appearing on click but its working in responsiveness when the menu collapsed. When I click on Dropdown caret this is happening. On click it is opening but not visible?

Can anyone point the reason that what is this?

This is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8q88jrtr/) to understand the code

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

[image]

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Fiddle your code may help you to get the issue fixed.

Comment: updated the code and fiddle

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a> -->
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
          </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

hope it works for you! Thank you.

Comment: why? What is reason behind it? what you want exactly?

Comment: He has no issues with the wide screen. My drop down menu works fine on small screen it is not showing in wide screen.

Comment: Then my first answer (without edit) is okay for you ?

Comment: I didn't see any answer what you have given?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143734/discussion-between-divyesh-gausvami-and-ijunaidfarooq).

Answer (score 0):

I check your fiddle . 
There need to enqueue jquery library to your code. 
Bootsrape js require jQuery library to enque first

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included jQuery in your fiddle and the order should be `jquery.min.js->bootstrap.js` here is your updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8q88jrtr/4/

Answer (score 0):

I think @Malay Solanki  is right. There is an error in the console related to the jquery library. I updated your fiddle check it out

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8q88jrtr/3/)

```
include jquery
```

Answer (score -2):

Please share your code to find out the problem.
But you can try
    .navbar{width:100%}